# How to disable textbox for no data and retain (textbox) till save button click

Tags: angular

I am working on angular2. If I select an option from drop down list, I get the details of the selection. If any data is missing a textbox is shown and if data exists it is shown as a label. Hence,I applied the following logic:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="options" >Select product:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="options"  name="options" #optionsRef (change)="onSelectOption(optionsRef.value)">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.name">{{product.name}}</option>
            </select>
            </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="name">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div *ngIf="!obj.editOn"  style="padding-top:5px">{{obj.name}}</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="obj.name" #nameRef="ngModel" placeholder="Enter name" *ngIf="obj.editOn">
            <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="editDetails(obj)">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="saveDetails(objbj)">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="id">Product Id:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <div *ngIf="obj.id || (!obj.editOn)" style="padding-top:5px">{{obj.id}}</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" [(ngModel)]="obj.id" #idRef="ngModel"  placeholder="Enter product Id" *ngIf="(!obj.id || obj.editOn)">
            <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="editDetails(obj)">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="saveDetails(obj)">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The array of objects is defined as below in conponent.ts :

```
private products = [{ name : "ABC" , id : null},
                     { name : "XYZ" , id : 101},
                     { name : "Geeta", id : null}
                    ];
```

An empty object `obj` which takes the particular object from `products` array depending on the selection.

If data of `id` is `null` then textbox should appear. The problem is when I enter any data it reads the first character and instanly changes to label and does not wait for save button click.

On click functions are below:

```
editDetails(selection:any ) {
    selection.editOn = true; 
}

saveDetails(selection:any ) {
    selection.editOn = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic tells that you just cannot use `obj.id` in the condition that shows or hides this input in the template. You just need to manage `obj.editOn` flag in the code in such a manner that it would switch id edit mode correctly. So, you could do something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!obj.editOn" style="padding-top:5px">{{obj.id}}</div>
<input <...skipped irrelevant things...> [(ngModel)]="obj.id" *ngIf="obj.editOn" (blur)="updateEditModeForId(obj)">
```

and in the code of the component:

```
updateEditModeForId(obj) {
    obj.editOn = !obj.id;
}

initialize() {
    ...
    var obj = ...; // getting it from somewhere
    updateEditModeForId(obj);
    ...
}
```

This is not production-ready code, it may not even compile, I'm just trying to convey the general idea. For example, you can choose not to use a blur event and to just rely on pressing `Save` button for `id` property. Also, you will probably want to use a separate flag for managing editing mode for it.